# Laravel getLogout with Logout Message

Tags: laravel, messagebox, laravel-blade

I want to get a 'Logged Out' message after I've got logged out. I've found this:

```
public function getLogout()
{
    // Copy over the stuff from the getLogout function in the trait

    // Add your flash message

    // You are done ;)
}
```

there is written I need to copy the stuff from the getLogout function and just add the flash message. But where is the getLogout code? I can't find it. And is there any other way?

I tried this:

```
public function getLogout()
{
    Session::flash('message', 'You have been logged out!');
    return redirect(action('Auth\AuthController@getLogout'));
}
```

and on the blade I'm getting directed after the loggout:

```
@if (Session::has('message'))
    <div class="alert alert-info">{{ Session::get('message') }}
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    </div>
@endif
```

But this haven't worked for me. Does anybody knows a solution? I've just want a "You have been logged out" message.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you have tested that the action is actually called?

The problem lies with your redirecting. Flash messages only stick around for 1 request (if not kept around manually). You are redirecting to logout, which redirects the user to whatever page they are going to. (probably '/')

After the first redirect your flash messages will be emptied, so the following redirect has no flash messages left.

Change (or create) your Auth\AuthController@logout like this.

```
public function logout()
{
    Auth::logout();

    return redirect('/')
        ->with('message', 'You have been logged out');
}
```

Or check `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers@logout` for stuff to copy paste..

It is important that the location you are redirecting to is accessible by guests, otherwise you'll get another redirect, which will clear your session vars.

Comment: well, the logout works now but the logout message does not appear :o

Comment: Got it! I just had a little syntax mistake :) thanks alot!

Answer (score -1):

you can use:

```
return redirect(action('Auth\AuthController@getLogout'))->with('message','Your Message');
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others

Answer (score -3):

The getLogout function is defined in AuthenticatesUsers trait (Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php).

By default, it just calls the logout function.

Try instead:

```
public function getLogout()
{
    Session::flash('message', 'You have been logged out!');
    return $this->logout();
}
```

Comment: this just gives me an: Method [logout] does not exist. :/

Comment: Which Laravel version are you using?